# get column number from label in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

how to get the column number from label in DataFrame, for instance.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame({'key': ['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'],
                'data1': range(6)},
                index=['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6'])
In[31]:df
Out[31]:
```

```
      data1 key
a1      0   b
a2      1   b
a3      2   a
a4      3   c
a5      4   a
a6      5   b
```

if I run

```
df.iloc[2,1]
```

it would return 'a'.
the question is,  I just know the column label is 'key', how can I get the column number? then I can use df.iloc.

you see, .ix is deprecated in pandas, else I would just use df.ix[2,'key'].

I just know how the solution for the similar question: get column label from column number. for instance,

```
df.loc['a3',df.iloc[:,[1]].columns]
```

Comment: why not simply use `df['key'].iloc[2]` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) or [`Index.searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.searchsorted.html):

```
a = df.columns.get_loc('key')
print (a)
1
```

---

```
a = df.columns.searchsorted('key')
print (a)
1
```

Then `iloc` works nice:

```
a = df.iloc[2, df.columns.get_loc('key')]
print (a)
a
```